# activity_main.xml and activity_main.xml(v14)

Tags: android, xml

I've created a duplicate file of my `activity_main.xml`. Why? Because I was trying to solve a problem regarding the minimum API required. So there's that red bulb notification in android studio, I clicked that, and applied the possible fix. What it did was it created that second xml file. Now, it's no use since I solved the problem in another why. This time, I'm editing the original xml file. However, when I run the program, it will display the layout of the duplicate xml file. What should I do?

Comment: How did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity.java` file there's a line that says:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

you can set any other xml file (with any name) there as a layout. Change it to the new layout's name.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve your problem,

1. if your are using the `activity_main.xml` file for your layout then delete your duplicate file `activity_main.xml`. Go to your `MainActivity.java` file and 
   under `onCreate()` method put this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` 
   this will link it to your `activity_main.xml` file in which your layout is defined.
2. if your trying to resolve the minimum API problem then right click on your Project-> Properties->Android, under Project Build Target choose a lower API then Apply and Ok to save the changes.